# Stream Screen from one machine and webcam from another

Tags: streaming

I want to start doing some Twitch.tv streaming, but don't have a webcam. I have a gaming PC desktop and an OSX laptop with eyesight webcam built in. I was wondering if it is possible to stream the webcam feed over the network to my desktop and add it to my desktop stream as you would normally on OBS or similar.

Comment: Also if there's a better forum for this question please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a lot like  [share desktop to laptop to stream from laptop](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14764/share-desktop-to-laptop-to-stream-from-laptop/14769#14769)  (that guy's goal was lower CPU load on his desktop, but same solution.)

Use the usual streaming setup on your desktop, but with high bitrate.  stream to laptop, decode there.  overlay webcam, encode for normal streaming, send that output to Twitch.tv.

IDK what it takes to send streams to twitch, or to receive streams from desktop streaming software.  Assuming you can get ffmpeg to do it, and read from your webcam, use the `overlay` filter to combine the streams, and `-c:v libx264 -preset medium` to encode to h.264.  Not sure what you'd need to do to get ffmpeg's output to go to Twitch.tv.